# Working With 2D Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, logic, output

I'm trying to repost this question but with more clarification. Given my code below, I wish to output the total of each column and each row. The row totals should be to the right of the last element in that particular row and the column total should be below the final element in a given column. Please see the comment in the beginning of my program to understand what I wish my output to be. How could I go about doing this? Also I want to print out the main diagonal of a given user-inputted array. So in the code below the main diagonal would be outputted as {1,3,5}. Thank you!

```
/*
                    1 2 3 Row 0: 6
                    2 3 4 Row 1: 9
                    3 4 5 Row 2: 12
          Column 0: 6
           Column 1:  9
             Column 2:  12

*/
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Test2Darray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner scan =new Scanner(System.in); //creates scanner object

        System.out.println("How many rows to fill?"); //prompts user how many numbers they want to store in array
        int rows = scan.nextInt(); //takes input for response

        System.out.println("How many columns to fill?");
        int columns = scan.nextInt();
        int[][] array2d=new int[rows][columns]; //array for the elements

        for(int row=0;row<rows;row++) 
            for (int column=0; column < columns; column++)
            {
            System.out.println("Enter Element #" + row + column + ": "); //Stops at each element for next input
            array2d[row][column]=scan.nextInt(); //Takes in current input
            }

        for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        {
            for( int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
                {
                System.out.print(array2d[row][column] + " ");
                }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("\n");



        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Edit this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820588/summing-up-a-2d-array instead of posting a whole new question about the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] colSums = new int[array2d.length];
int[] mainDiagonal = new int[array2d.length];

for (int i = 0; i < array2d[0].length; i++) {
    int rowSum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < array2d.length; j++) {
        colSums[j] += array2d[i][j];
        rowSum += array2d[i][j];
        System.out.print(array2d[i][j] + " ");
        if (i == j) mainDiagonal[i] = array2d[i][j];
    }
    System.out.println(" Row " + i + ": " + rowSum);
}
System.out.println();
for (int i = 0; i < colSums.length; i++) 
    System.out.println("Column " + i + ": " + colSums[i]);
System.out.print("\nMain diagonal: { ");
for (Integer e : mainDiagonal) System.out.print(e + " ");
System.out.println("}");
```

Comment: Interesting. What was incorrect? Also would it be hard to align the column total with each column like I did in my comment above?

Comment: i = array2d[i].length produced an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.  Formatting the output shouldn't be too difficult if you just include the right number of spaces in your print statement.